# Select Pipe delimited values

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I have a scenario to select individual values from delimited string.

Example:

```
declare @Test varchar(100) = 'ABC|DEF|GHI'
```

Since the database is SQL Server 2008 version I cannot use split function.

Looking for the best way to split and select each values separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own custom function in SQL server to split the string. You can use the below function for this...

```
Create FUNCTION SplitString(@str VARCHAR(8000), @delimiter Varchar(1))
RETURNS  @Temp Table ( item varchar(100))
as Begin

Declare @i as int=0
Declare @j as int=0

Set @j = (Len(@str) - len(REPLACE(@str,@delimiter,'')))

While @i  < = @j
Begin
  if @i  < @j
  Begin
      Insert into @Temp 
      Values(SUBSTRING(@str,1,Charindex(@delimiter,@str,1)-1))
      set @str = right(@str,(len(@str)- Charindex(@delimiter,@str,1)))
  End
  Else
  Begin
     Insert into @Temp Values(@str)
  End
 Set @i = @i + 1
End

return;
End
go

select * from dbo.SplitString('ABC|DEF|GHI', '|')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can work something with CharIndex() to find your delimiters and then use SubString() to grab between them:

```
Declare @Test varchar(100) = 'ABC|DEF|GHI'

Declare @d1 Int = CharIndex('|',@Test,1)
Declare @d2 Int = CharIndex('|',@Test,@d1+1)


Select 
Substring(@Test,1,@d1-1) As f1,
Substring(@Test,@d1+1,@d2-@d1-1) As f2,
Substring(@Test,@d2+1,len(@Test)-@d2) As f3
```

Result:

```
f1  f2  f3
ABC DEF GHI
```

Answer (score -1):

This is too long for a comment.  The best approach is to not use delimited values.  Instead, you could use a table variable:

```
declare @Test table (val varchar(100));

insert into @Test(val)
    values ('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI');
```

Voila.  No issue.

Comment: I am getting delimited values from source, which is not in control for edit